# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, azure, sharepoint, fetch

I am trying to install a module on SharePoint and I am getting some JSON parse errors that I can't seem to overcome and fix - I did some research and I am still unable to link why it's causing an unexpected token error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.b.onreadystatechange (CPXHRLoader.js:190)

Here is the code:

```
loadImagesJSON: function() {
    function e(a) {
        var b = new XMLHttpRequest;
        b.open("GET", a, !0);
        b.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        b.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (4 == b.readyState && 200 === b.status) {
                ++f;
                var a = b.responseText;
                0 == a.length ? f == d.length -
                    1 && d[f].call(null, "") : (a = a.slice(54, a.length - 1), a = JSON.parse(a), f >= d.length || (f == d.length - 1 ? d[f].call(null, a) : e(d[f])))
            }
        };
        b.send()
    }
    if ("file" == window.location.protocol.substr(0, 4)) w.apply(null, arguments);
    else {
        for (var d = [], a = 0; a < arguments.length; a++)
            if ("[object Array]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[a]))
                for (var c = arguments[a], b = 0; b < c.length; b++) d.push(c[b]);
            else d.push(arguments[a]);
        var f = 0;
        e(d[0])
    }
},
```

This is what's included in my network tab:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfVTH.png

Has anyone come across issues with SharePoint blocking parse requests? When I upload the files to my Azure web app and include a `web.config` file with a pointer to JSON as a MIME type it loads perfectly, it just won't load in SharePoint.

Comment: The issue is because the `responseText` is not correctly formatted JSON, so the `JSON.parse(a)` is throwing the error. Could you check what the exact responsetext is in the network tab of the developer tools, and edit your question to include it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Sorry about that, I have included the network tab now.

Comment: @Sema What's the actual response? The screenshot you attached only showed that the call was made. If you click on it you should be able to see the actual response content in the right pane under the Response tab